# How can I convert my html structure to use with Text widget?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, converters

I have a HTML text. For instance:

```
"<p>Hello everyone! </p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>Is it work?</p>"
```

well,I wanna use this with Text Widget in my Flutter Project. I have already looked the html package but I couldn't .

For Instance:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart'

var document=parse("<p>Hello everyone! </p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>Is it work?</p>");
```

for the use in text widget:

```
Text(document.querySelectorAll("Div > p")[0].innerHtml);
```

How can I handle it? Many Thanks..

Comment: What was the problem with the HTML package?

Comment: I couldn't convert String and use with Text widget.

Comment: "querrySelectorAll("Div > p")": there is no div in your html.